# loop is ignored - instructions only executed once

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pic, microchip

I cannot get loops to work.  I have tried a for and while and I have the same problem with both.  The instructions within the loop (alternating flashing LEDs) are executed once, then the micro resets and does the initial double LED flash again.  Can someone see some logic error?

Using PIC16f688 and XC8 compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int count;

    TRISA = 0b00000000;
    TRISC = 0b00000000;

    PORTA = 0b00000011;
    __delay_ms(1000);
    PORTA = 0b00000000;

    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++) {

        PORTA = 0b00000001;
        __delay_ms(1000);
        PORTA = 0b00000010;
        __delay_ms(1000);

    }

    PORTA = 0b00000011;
    __delay_ms(1000);
    PORTA = 0b00000000;

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: When You unroll the loop (copy & paste it's contents 5 times instead of for loop) does it work ok? What happens, when You change the delays to 500ms? Also make sure Your watchdog is off.

Comment: it was the watchdog.  It was timed perfectly to make it look like a logic error of somesort.  Thanks.

Comment: @Terryl Suggest you submit your own answer and accept it to complete this post.

Answer (score 1):

this was a watchdog timer issue.  It turns out the default watch dog length of time was exactly the length of time of the first iteration of the loop so it looked like the loop was just skipping out.

To disable the watchdog timer with my set up (MPLABX, XC8 compiler, PIC16f688) the code is:

```
#pragma config WDTE = OFF
```